# Yum update without updating or asking to update

Tags: linux, yum

How do I run `yum update` but don't update or ask to update, just output the packages available for update and then exit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yum list updates`​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​